# System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException thrown when consuming wcf service on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, iis

I created a WCF service to upload file and the WCF service is hosted on windows IIS. I also have a client to consume this WCF service over HTTPS and currently the client and the service are on the same machine. The code is shown below:

IService1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfService1
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {


        [OperationContract]
        void UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request);


        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }


    [MessageContract]
    public class RemoteFileInfo : IDisposable
    {
        [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
        public string FilePath;

        /*
        [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
        public string DestinationDirectory;
        */

        [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
        public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (FileByteStream != null)
            {
                FileByteStream.Close();
                FileByteStream = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Service1.cvs.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WcfService1
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {

        public void UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request)
        {
            FileStream targetStream = null;
            Stream sourceStream = request.FileByteStream;

            //string destinationDirectory = request.DestinationDirectory;
            Console.WriteLine(request.FilePath);
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(request.FilePath);

            string filePath = Path.Combine("C:\\upload", fileName);

            using (targetStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create,
                                  FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {


                const int bufferLen = 65000;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
                int count = 0;
                while ((count = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) > 0)
                {

                    targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                targetStream.Close();
                sourceStream.Close();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Client code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ClientApp.ServiceReference1;

namespace ClientApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Service1Client client = new Service1Client();

            string FilePath1 = "C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\data.csv";
            System.IO.FileStream stream1 =
            new System.IO.FileStream("C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\data.csv",
            System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

            string dest = "C:\\upload";
            client.UploadFile(FilePath1, stream1);
            client.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

This client code throw exception on the line " **client.UploadFile(FilePath1, stream1);**" :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:53673/Service1.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

However, if I launch browser to access the site, I can access Service1.svc successfully(which means I configure the IIS and post the service to IIS correctly) like the screen shot below:

[image]

I would like to know where the problem is? Thanks in advance!

Edit:

The orignal client's App.config is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:53673/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And based on the suggestion, I change it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpsBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_IService1" />
            </basicHttpsBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://localhost:53673/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpsBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpsBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpsBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Now, I got another error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://localhost:53673/Service1.svc. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.
```

I don't think there is a problem with the certificate if I can launch the site from browser. In addition, I use self-signed certificate and client and server are on the same machine. I am thinking if it is that I cannot change the client's app.config directly and there is something wrong with the configuration of the service? I noticed that every time I update the service in the client service reference, the http binding will appear in the app.config. I would like to know what is the right way to deal with it?

Comment: Although you have obscured the URL in the screenshot, it's obvious that it isn't `http://localhost:53673/Service1.svc` which is what your client is pointing to.

Comment: The browser screenshot uses https while the error message you include says http ('There was no endpoint listening at http: //localhost:53673/Service1.svc'). Change the url used by the app to use https

Comment: I would like to know how to change the url used by the app? I mean which file I should modify?

Answer (score 1):

Change the client app.config file to point to correct address. It currently points to:

```
<endpoint address="https://localhost:53673/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpsBinding"
```

change the address part to one that is masked in screenshot.